# jQuery Striping with Some Elements Hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery selector like the following:

```
$('.someClass div div .specificChildClass:nth-child(even)').addClass('alternateLine');
```

This stripes just as I want it to UNLESS there's a hidden element.  I need the selector to take hidden elements into account and NOT factor them in to the striping.  This way, the visible elements are striped properly on the page.

I tried changing my selector to this:

```
$('.someClass div div .specificChildClass:visible:nth-child(even)').addClass('alternateLine');
```

and then:

```
$('.someClass div div .specificChildClass:not(.hiddenClass):nth-child(even)').addClass('alternateLine');
```

Is there an easy solution to this?  I know I can iterate through a .each loop with an iterator and check each, mod the iterator to decide odd or even, but I thought there was probably a better way.

Comment: what is the problem with :visible? it should do what you need.

Comment: Yeah, but it was the nth-child call that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`:even`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/even) -

```
$('.someClass div div .specificChildClass:visible:even')
  .addClass('alternateLine');
```

`nth-child` refers to DOM structure, this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I assumed nth-child was using the DOM structure after I saw the results, just wasn't sure how to fix that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    $('.someClass div div .specificChildClass:visible:nth-child(even)')
    .filter(function(i) {
           $(this).is(':visible').addClass('alternateLine');
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use `:not(:hidden)`

```
$('.someClass div div .specificChildClass:not(:hidden):even').addClass('alternateLine');
```